# How to use map.nodes in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
map = d3.layout.pack().size(size);
map.nodes({children: centers});
```

How to acheive this in d3 v4+

I an trying to achive :

```
var getCenters = function (vname, size) {
          var centers, map;
           centers = _.uniq(_.pluck(rawData, vname)).map(function (d) {
             return {name: d, value: 1};
           });

 map = d3.layout.pack().size(size);
    map.nodes({children: centers});
          return centers;
        };
```

Comment: See this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530

Comment: Not helpfull!! @VinodLouis

Comment: Then probably make a fiddle with your data and describe where your are facing problem only that way then can anyone help you